# How to save current url in session in java

Tags: java, session, servlets

How to save current url in session in java? And if from my servlet i want to redirect request to this url, how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:** Find out the current URL - use [HttpServletRequest.getRequestURI](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI%28%29) *(or getRequestURL, depending on exactly what you need)*

**Step 2:** Add it to the session: use [HttpSession.setAttribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html)

*Later*

**Step 3:** Get it out of session: `HttpSession.getAttribute`

**Step 4:** Redirect to that URL [HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 2):

You can forward with RequestDispatcher

```
  RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(uri);
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

and you can extract the current url from the request